# jquery cookie issue: $.cookie is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I know this question has been asked multiple times. I looked at many answers but couldn't find a solution.

I am trying to load jquery.cookie.js script. Here is how:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/javascript.js"></script>
```

This is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var jobStats_class = $.cookie('jobStats');

    // Add toggle feature
    $('.jobStats caption').click(function () {
        $('.jobStats th,.jobStats td').slideToggle('1000');
    });

    $('.ricSubscriptions caption').click(function () {
        $('.ricSubscriptions th,.ricSubscriptions td').slideToggle('1000');

    });

    $('.trthJobStatus caption').click(function () {
        $('.trthJobStatus th,.trthJobStatus td').slideToggle('1000');
    });
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you tell us if the `jquery.cookie.js` request succeeds?

Comment: @tvanfosson - it does! no error reported regarding loading of the actual file.

Comment: URL for the site with the problem?

Comment: Which version of jquery.cookie are you using ?

Comment: @huggilou - I am using 2.0.0 from github. I just followed Alex's suggestion and it solved the problem!

Comment: @HimanshuGupta : The real problem was that since the version 2.0, [`jquery-cookie`](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) has moved to [`js-cookie`](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie). Now to access to the library you have to pass through `Cookies` variable and no more througth `$`

Comment: @huggilou - ah that makes sense. thanks for the explanation. Do you recommend using the newer version or sticking with the older version for now?

Comment: @HimanshuGupta : I will recommand you to use the new version because it's still maintained.

Comment: The version 1.5.1 is the latest version that uses the jQuery namespace in js-cookie repository. The `v2.0.0-beta.1` changelog make it explicit in the first paragraph: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/releases/tag/v2.0.0-beta.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since version 2.0, [`jquery-cookie`](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) project has moved to [`js-cookie`](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) project.

Now you can't handle cookies with `$` variable (because this library didn't really use special functions of jQuery). Now, you have to use `Cookies` variable :

### Create a cookie

```
//OLD
$.cookie('name', 'value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
//NEW
Cookies.set('name', 'value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```

### Read a cookie

```
//OLD
$.cookie('name');
//NEW
Cookies.get('name');
```

### Read all cokies

```
//OLD
$.cookie();
//NEW
Cookies.get();
```

### Delete a cookie

```
//OLD
$.removeCookie('name');
//NEW
Cookies.remove('name');
```

Comment: Small correction, `js-cookie` didn't started with the version 2.0, it started with the version 1.5.0 that implements the `Cookies` global and still maintains backwards compatibility with `$` namespace. `jquery-cookie` repository is frozen in version 1.4.1: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/releases. `js-cookie` contains all versions, 1.4.1 and onwards: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/releases

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot

Answer (score 2):

Your script path is the problem. Try this cdn:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! That solves it! I was using the latest version from gitHub which I believe is v2.0.0.